# how to query for month and weekday?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a query where I'm doing something like this

```
 query =
  from(
    u in User,
    where: u.user_id == ^user_id,
    group_by: [
      fragment("date_part(?,?)::int", "month", u.inserted_at),
      u.user_id
    ],
    select: %{
      month: fragment("date_part(?,?)::int", "month", u.inserted_at),
      weekly: filter(count(u.user_id), fragment("date_trunc('week', ?) = date_trunc('week', current_timestamp)", u.inserted_at)),
      monthly: count(u.user_id),
    }
  )
```

I'm trying to get a result where I want to know how many users are inserted in every month and how many on weekdays and weekends?

result will be something like this

```
[
  %{month: 10, users: 5, weekday: 2, weekend: 3},
  %{month: 9, users: 5, weekday: 1, weekend: 4}
]
```

I don't how to go ahead after this please suggest me something

Comment: Where does the binding `t` come from? Maybe you mean `u`?

Comment: Yes that is u. Wait I'll change it

Comment: Does it work now? If not, try adding a pin before `"month"`, like `^"month"`, or just inline it into the fragment expression like `fragment("date_part('month', ?)", u.inserted_at)`.

Comment: For a month it's working fine. I want it for weekdays and weekends

Comment: I don't know how to extract that

Comment: For weekdays, you can use the function `date_part('dow', some_date)` or `date_part('isodow', some_date)`. `dow` stands for "Day of Week". The range of `dow` is between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday), while `isodow` is between 1 (Monday) and 7 (Sunday)

Comment: And that's just PostgreSQL dialect. Don't know the corresponding ways in other databases, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I think this can work but the problem is I want it every month. If I'm using this it will return the same weekdays for the 10th month to the 9th month.

Comment: I dont know how to group by it together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some SQL statements in PostgreSQL dialect.

```sql
SELECT
  date_part('year', users.inserted_at) AS year,  -- remove this line if you think January 2020 and January 2021 are the same month.
  date_part('month', users.inserted_at) AS month,
  date_part('isodow', users.inserted_at) >= 6 AS weekend,
  COUNT(users.id) AS "count"
FROM
  users
GROUP BY
  year,  -- remove this line if you think January 2020 and January 2021 are the same month.
  month,
  weekend
ORDER BY
  year ASC,  -- remove this line if you think January 2020 and January 2021 are the same month.
  month ASC,
  weekend ASC
```

You can't get the answer you want by a SQL query only, because the aggregates of `users` and `weekend`/`weekday` are on different granularity. You have to do some calculations in RAM.

Comment: date_part('isodow', users.inserted_at) >= 6 AS weekend,

Isn't this part will give me a boolean value?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can't aggregate on different granularity, so this should your best shot.